# Return in python if/elif/else

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, one-liner

I have a program, but it is not important.

```py
from collections import Counter

def balance(left, right, result = 0):
    wages = {'!': 2, '?': 3}
    for key in Counter(left).keys():
        result += Counter(left).get(key) * wages.get(key)
    for key_ in Counter(right).keys():
        result -= Counter(right).get(key_) * wages.get(key_)
    if result == 0:
        return 'Balance'
    return 'Left' if result > 0 else 'Right'
```

Source for interesting: https://www.codewars.com/kata/57fb44a12b53146fe1000136

Is it possible to write this piece of code in one line?

```py
if result == 0:
    return 'Balance'
return 'Left' if result > 0 else 'Right'
```

Comment: `return 'Balance' if result == 0 else ('Left' if result > 0 else 'Right')` maybe

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Conditional expressions (sometimes called a "ternary operator")](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
def balance(result: int) -> str:
    return 'Right' if result < 0 else 'Left' if result > 0 else 'Balance'

print(f'{balance(-1) = }')
print(f'{balance(0) = }')
print(f'{balance(1) = }')
```

**Output:**

```
balance(-1) = 'Right'
balance(0) = 'Balance'
balance(1) = 'Left'
```